# Oracle SQL -- remove partial duplicate from string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table with a column with strings that looke like this:

```
static-text-here/1abcdefg1abcdefgpxq
```

From this string `1abcdefg` is repeated twice, so I want to remove that partial string, and return:

```
static-text-here/1abcdefgpxq
```

I can make no guarantees about the length of the repeat string. In pure SQL, how can this operation be performed?

Comment: What if there are multiple repetitions? What with things like `aaaaa`? Is that `aa` twice followed by `a` (resulting in `aaa`) or is it `a` repeated 5 times, resulting in `a`?

Comment: @m.buettner There are not multiple repetitions. The "string that repeats" starts right after the static text and repeats exactly once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee a minimum length of the repeated string, something like this would work:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE
   (input, 
   '(.{10,})(.*?)\1+', 
   '\1') "Less one repetition" 
   from tablename tn where ...;
```

I believe this can be expanded to meet your case with some cleverness.

Answer (score 7):

```
regexp_replace('static-text-here/1abcdefg1abcdefgpxq', '/(.*)\1', '/\1')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e58e/2)

Comment: +1 This solution also works with PostgreSQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/85101/1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you might be pushing SQL beyond what it is capable/designed for.  Is it possible for you to handle this situation programmatically in the layer that lays under the data layer where this type of thing can be more easily handled?

Answer (score 0):

The `REPLACE` function should be enough to solve the problem.

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (text varchar(100));

INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('pxq');
INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('static-text-here/pxq');
INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('static-text-here/1abcdefgpxq');
INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('static-text-here/1abcdefg1abcdefgpxq');
```

Query:

```
SELECT text, REPLACE(text, '1abcdefg1abcdefg', '1abcdefg') AS text2
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
TEXT                                    TEXT2
pxq                                     pxq
static-text-here/pxq                    static-text-here/pxq
static-text-here/1abcdefgpxq            static-text-here/1abcdefgpxq
static-text-here/1abcdefg1abcdefgpxq    static-text-here/1abcdefgpxq
```

AFAIK the `REPLACE` function is not in the SQL99 standard, but most DBMSs support it. I tested it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d1b3/2), and it works with MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle and MS SQL Server.

Comment: You're hardcoding the repeating string here, while it could be any repeating string.

Comment: @Jerry I see. So REPLACE is enough only when the there are only a small number of possible strings which can be the repeated substring, and all of them are known in advance.