# Oracle remove repeating characters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In order to implement password complexity I need a function that can remove repeating characters (in order to generate passwords that will meet the password complexity requirements). So a string like weeeeee1 will not be allowed since the e is repeated. I need a function that will instead return we1, where the repeating characters have been removed. Oracle PL/SQL or straight sql must be used.

I found [Oracle SQL -- remove partial duplicate from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473719/oracle-sql-remove-partial-duplicate-from-string), but this does not work with my weeeeee1 test case, since it only replaces with one iteration, therefore returning weee1.

I'm not trying to test for no repeating characters. I'm trying to change a repeating character string into a non-repeating character string.

Comment: Won't removing characters risk it failing other requirements, specifically minimum length? Without seeing how it's generated in the first place, it might be simpler to throw away any generated value that fails any test and start again; depends how often they'll fail, how long they take to generate, whether that gives acceptable performance, etc...

Comment: Is really `we1`  a more secure password than `weeeeee1` ?!?

Comment: I will use a randomly generated number. The only problem is then to remove the possible repeating characters. So length and security is not the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can achieve your goal using regexp_replace. Or do I missed something?

```
select regexp_replace(:password, '(.)\1+','\1') 
  from dual;
```

---

Here is an example:

```
with t as (select 'weeee1' password from dual
           union select 'wwwwweeeee11111' from dual
           union select 'we1' from dual)

select regexp_replace(t.password, '(.)\1+','\1') 
  from t;
```

Producing:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(T.PASSWORD,'(.)\1+','\1')
we1
we1
we1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select regexp_replace('weeeeee1', '(.)\1+', '\1') val from dual

VAL
---
we1
```

Comment: I'm not trying to test for no repeating characters. I'm trying to change a repeating character string into a non-repeating character string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably,

1. use the returned value (weee1) to check again and replace
2. take each letter of the word and check in entire word that more than 1 existence or not.

Comment: This answer doesn't stand alone - can you add more information so it can stand with the question in isolation?